# OAuth2 Server implementation

Tags: php, symfony, oauth

I'm trying to implement an OAuth2 Server on Symfony2, have tested the FOSOAuthServerBundle and now i'm trying to test bshaffer/oauth2-server-bundle. Problem there s almost no read me and i dont know really how to use it. Has anybody tested it? Some little examples would be much appreciated. Thanx in advance.

Comment: And why not the FOSOAuthServerBundle? ;)

Comment: I didn t say i wouldn t use FOSOAuthServerBundle, just wanted to test few bundles before actually making a decision. For the moment i m just trying and testing.